# What is the gel used for covering the strain gauge in the load cell?

Tags: sensors

We have one imported strain gauge load cell, which shown open circuit in the input impedance. I removed the protective gel and corrected the wiring. Now the load cell is working. But I want to cover the strain gauge with the gel for the protection against moisture and dust. I want to know the product/technical name of the gel. please see the image. the blue arrow pointing the material that I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Typically, this is some kind of silicone sealant type of gel to prevent moisture ingress, but each load manufacturer will use something different, so your best option is to ask the supplier.

Comment: “Potting compound” is the generic term for such materials. But much like knowing something is “adhesive” or “paint”, that will only get you in the general area...